# Dependent dropdown list in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to put a pair of dependent dropdown list wherein the first list is the collection of controllers and sencond list is the collection of access points. When I select controller1, the second dropdown should show me the options to select an access point connected to controller1 only. I have written the following code taking help from one of the answered question but unable to complete it due to my limited knowledge of programming. Can anyone please help me in completing this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>UH WiFi Utilization Report</title>

</head>

<table class="maintable">
 <tr style="line-height:50px;">
 <td>Select Controller</td>
 <td>:</td>
 <td>
 <select>
 <option values="">--Select--</option>
 <option> controller1</option>
 <option> controller2</option>
 <option> controller3</option>
 <option> controller4</option>

 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="line-height:20px;">
 <td>Select Access Point</td>
 <td>:</td>
 <td>
 <select style="float:left;" id="subcats">
 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

var Controller1 = [
    {display: "AccessPoint1", value: "Access Point1"},
    {display: "AccessPoint2", value: "Access Point2"},
    {display: "AccessPoint3", value: "Access Point3"},
    {display: "AccessPoint4", value: "Access Point4"}];


var Controller2 = [
    {display: "AccessPoint5", value: "Access Point5"},
    {display: "AccessPoint6", value: "Access Point6"},
    {display: "AccessPoint7", value: "Access Point7"},
    {display: "AccessPoint8", value: "Access Point8"}];


var Controller3 = [
    {display: "AccessPoint9", value: "Access Point9"},
    {display: "AccessPoint10", value: "Access Point10"},
    {display: "AccessPoint11", value: "Access Point11"},
    {display: "AccessPoint12", value: "Access Point12"}];


var Controller4 = [
    {display: "AccessPoint13", value: "Access Point13"},
    {display: "AccessPoint14", value: "Access Point14"},
    {display: "AccessPoint15", value: "Access Point15"},
    {display: "AccessPoint16", value: "Access Point16"}];

$("#controllers").change(function() {
     var parent = $(this).val();
     switch(parent){
     case 'controller1':
     list(Controller1);
     break;
     case 'controller2':
     list(Controller2);
     break;
     case 'controller3':
     list(Controller3);
     break;
     case 'controller4':
     list(Controller4);
     break;
     default: //default child option is blank
     $("#subcats").html('');
     break;
     }
     });

function list(array_list)
{
$("#subcats").html(""); //reset child options
$(array_list).each(function (i) { //populate child options
$("#subcats").append("<option value=""+array_list[i].value+"">"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
});
}


</script>   

<body>

<body>

</body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where does it fail to you?

Comment: As I see it, this line should fail: `$("#subcats").append("<option value=""+array_list[i].value+"">"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");`, as you are closing and opening the "" when you set the "value" field. Try using `$("#subcats").append("<option value=\""+array_list[i].value+"\">"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");`. \" means a " which should not be read by JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example code I made [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pf85onp/2/)

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<table class="maintable">
 <tr style="line-height:50px;">
 <td>Select Controller</td>
 <td>:</td>
 <td>
 <select name="controllers">
 <option values="0">--Select--</option>
 <option value="1"> controller1</option>
 <option value="2"> controller2</option>
 <option value="3"> controller3</option>
 <option value="4"> controller4</option>

 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="line-height:20px;">
 <td>Select Access Point</td>
 <td>:</td>
 <td>
 <select name="accessPoint" style="float:left;" id="subcats">
 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Some pointers

- Name your inputs
- Make sure your values are unique.

**edit**

- Add a value to your options.

---

**Jquery**

```
  var controllerData = new Array();;
  
  controllerData.push({});
  controllerData.push(
  [
    {display: "Access Point 1", value: "AccessPoint1"},
    {display: "Access Point 2", value: "AccessPoint2"},
    {display: "Access Point 3", value: "AccessPoint3"},
    {display: "Access Point 4", value: "AccessPoint4"}
    ]
  );
    controllerData.push(
  [
    {display: "Access Point 5", value: "AccessPoint5"},
    {display: "Access Point 6", value: "AccessPoint6"},
    {display: "Access Point 7", value: "AccessPoint7"},
    {display: "Access Point 8", value: "AccessPoint8"}
    ]
  );

    $(document).ready(function(){    
    $('SELECT[name="controllers"]').on('change', function(){
    console.log(controllerData);
        var selectValue = $(this).val();
      var selectAccessPoint = $("SELECT[name='accessPoint']");
      selectAccessPoint.empty();
      
      console.log("Select value " + selectValue +", controllerData size: "+ controllerData.length);
      
      if(selectValue < controllerData.length){
        console.log("Select value is accesible");
        for(i = 0; i < controllerData[selectValue].length; i++){
            console.log("Val:" + controllerData[selectValue] );
          selectAccessPoint.append("<option value=\""+controllerData[selectValue][i].value+"\">"+controllerData[selectValue][i].display +"</option>");
        }
      }else{
        selectAccessPoint.append("<option>- NO data -</option>");
      }
    });
  
  });
```

**edit**

- It might be better to think of your access Points as a matrix. By doing this you will enable your code to scale without messing with your function. You might even create a separate file for your access point data.
- The console.logs() are there only as help while you code, they must be removed afterwards.
- IDK if it is good practice, but I prefer getting the value of inputs by name. It helps me when working with forms.

**note:**

---

Comment: I shall complete the excercise in a while. I leave you the fiddle to get started.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I checked the fiddle.....works fine over there however the same code doesn't seem to work in my eclipse.........any clue?

Comment: Do you have jquery added to your html?

Comment: Try adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>` right before the script that has the function in the fiddle.